# Nginx: Googlebot Gets Temporarily Unreachable For Some Images

Tags: nginx

I use nginx as a reverse proxy. When I try to fetch my site using "Fetch as Google" I receive what looks like a 404 for some CDN-hosted images entirely randomly. Most load and render fine, but some not.

So it appears some resources on a CDN are not getting fetched properly and I believe nginx is to blame because I have a robots.txt on MaxCDN.

Why do resources get timeouts when rendered by Google / nginx?

What are the reasons for that?

Comment: Before making what could likely be incorrect assumptions, gather *data*. Logs are your friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

It was most likely nothing, however I wanted to be sure so here's what I did:

**1.** As pointed out in the comments, I should take better care of logging. While digging through nginx file I noticed it wasn't properly logging the real IPs. Then I made sure Google was crawling the site just fine.

See question: [How to properly set up access_log for nginx cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/768314/how-to-properly-set-up-access-log-for-nginx-cache/)

**2.** I also made sure to add the following to my vhost.

```
root /my/home/dir
```

I am going to report back here if it turns out it was a real problem (will know in a few days)