# How to properly set up access_log for nginx cache

Tags: nginx

I am trying to properly set up logging for nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache so that I can see IPs in *all* log files not just the domlogs

In my vhosts file I use:

```
access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/site.net combined;
```

But I also set up a microcache and in microcache.inc I use:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/microcache.log custom_microcache;
```

This works, but in the file microcache.log I don't see the real IP addresses that I can see in the domlog file, how would I do that?

This is what I have in my proxy.inc which works fine for the domlog to translate IPs

```
proxy_set_header   Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was fairly simple, I was using the wrong log_format and wasn't aware that I had to write my own.

Here is the log_format I ended up using:

```
log_format newlog '$remote_addr forwarded for $http_x_real_ip - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                      '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                      '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

Then in my microcache.inc file I declared this:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/microcache2.log newlog;
```

Now I have a proper log file for my cache with the real IPs